# Как в WPF MVVM сделать привязку данных к ComboBox

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой. Делаю приложение на WPF с использованием паттерна MVVM. Работу с базой данных осуществляю с помощью Entity Framework. Есть 2 таблицы: Сотрудники(ФИО, id должности) и Должности(id, название). Я хочу, чтобы на форме с сотрудниками, когда я выбираю одного из них, выводилась вся информация о нём (ФИО, должность и тд). Это я осуществил, создав класс EmployeesViewModel:

```
class EmployeesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    OpticsEntities db;
    private Employee selectedEmployees;
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }


    public Employee SelectedEmployees
    {
        get { return selectedEmployees; }
        set
        {
            selectedEmployees = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployees");
        }
    }

    public EmployeesViewModel()
    {
        db = new OpticsEntities();
        db.Employees.Load();
        Employees = db.Employees.Local;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    private RelayCommand addCommand;
    private RelayCommand saveCommand;
    private RelayCommand removeCommand;
    private RelayCommand changeCommand;

    public RelayCommand AddCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return addCommand ??
                (addCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                {
                    Employee employees = new Employee();
                    Employees.Insert(0, employees);
                    SelectedEmployees = employees;
                }));
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return saveCommand ??
                (saveCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                {
                    Employee employees = obj as Employee;
                    if (employees != null)
                    {
                        db.Employees.Add(employees);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }));
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand ChangeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return changeCommand ??
                (changeCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                {
                    Employee employees = obj as Employee;
                    if (employees != null)
                    {
                        var changeEmployees = db.Employees.Find(employees.id);
                        employees = changeEmployees;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

и представление:

```
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployees}" Margin="0,0,17,0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Path=lastname}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}">Add</Button>
        <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedEmployees}">Save</Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedEmployees}">
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Имя" />
        <TextBox>
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="firstname" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <DataErrorValidationRule />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Фамилия" />
        <TextBox>
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="lastname" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <DataErrorValidationRule />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Должность" />
        <TextBox>
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="post" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <DataErrorValidationRule />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Всё отлично работает. Можно добавить нового сотрудника и сохранить.
[image: Окно с сотрудниками]

Но проблема вот в чем. Поле "Должность" связано с таблицей "Должности" по внешнему ключу (id). И я хочу, чтобы вместо текстового поля с id должности был ComboBox, в котором бы находились названия всех должностей из таблицы "Должности". По умолчанию в нем была бы та должность, которой соответствует сотрудник, но можно было бы открыть ComboBox и присвоить ему другую. После нажатия на Save всё сохранилось бы в базе.

Максимум, что я смог сделать, это создать ComboBox, в котором будут отображаться эти должности. Но для этого пришлось сделать еще одну коллекцию во ViewModel и обращаться уже к ней в ItemsSource. Естественно, что бы я в ней не выбрал, никакой связи с сотрудником не будет, так как данные не связаны получается.

Как мне сделать, чтобы в ComboBox отображались должности из таблицы Должности, и при выборе одной из них она бы присваивалась полю Должность у Сотрудника? Напомню, что таблицы связаны внешним ключом по id должности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут достаточно много вариантов реализации, красивых и не очень, но если попробовать сделать с участием дополнительной коллекции моделей представления для каждой должности, как вы описали.

Пример искусственный, написан для демонстрации подхода к использованию тонкостей привязки `ComboBox` к данным, ни в коем случае не является примером реализации правильного MVVM.

Модели сущностей предметной области:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PostID { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Модели представления:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    public EmployeeViewModel(Employee model, IEnumerable<Post> posts)
    {
        Model = model;
        var postViewModels = new List<PostViewModel>();
        foreach (var post in posts)
        {
            postViewModels.Add(new PostViewModel(post));
        }
        PostViewModels = postViewModels;
    }

    public Employee Model { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PostViewModel> PostViewModels { get; private set; }
}

public class PostViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    public PostViewModel(Post model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    public Post Model { get; set; }
}
```

Класс `NotificationObject` просто реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`. В `DataContext` окна попадает `EmployeeViewModel`.

Разметка:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Name}" />
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PostViewModels}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Model.Name"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Model.PostID}"
              SelectedValuePath="Model.ID" />
</StackPanel>
```

Пример работающий, в `Combobox` будут отображаться названия должностей, при этом в объект `Employee` при выборе в `ComboBox` будет присваиваться валидный идентификатор должности.

У `ComboBox` есть несколько крайне полезных свойств.

1. `DisplayMemberPath` - путь к свойству сущности в `DataContext` элемента списка `ComboBox`, который будет отображаться в выпадающем списке и в основном теле `ComboBox`.
2. `SelectedValue` - наравне с `SelectedItem` можно биндиться к свойству `SelectedValue`, значение которого берётся по определённому пути из `SelectedItem`.
3. `SelectedValuePath` - путь от `SelectedItem`, по которому берётся `SelectedValue`.

В моём примере при выборе в `ComboBox` в его свойство `SelectedItem` попадает `PostViewModel`, а в свойство `SelectedValue` попадает уже искомый идентификатор должности. Это свойство и забиндено на `PostID` сущности `Employee`.

Надеюсь, принцип понятен и удастся перенести это на ваш случай.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Реализовал у себя, чуток по другому, но всё работает)