# Как использовать событие SelectionChanged в элементе ComboBox с помощью паттерна MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

Я новичек в UWP.

У меня есть ComboBox

````
```
// ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FontSizes}" тут подтягиваются элементы для ComboBox из ViewModel

   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FontSizes}"></ComboBox>
```
````

Мне нужно что бы при выборе элемента из ComboBox срабатывала команда SelectionChanged во ViewModel
Просто у ComboBox нет атрибута Command={Binding SelectionChanged}

Я использую паттерн MVVM. Технология UWP

Как это можно сделать ?

Comment: Самое простое - привязать `SelectedItem` и в `set` свойства вызывать нужную логику.

Comment: Вот пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648298/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-wpf-mvvm-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA-combobox